# Google Chrome кэширование после обновления / панель разработчика

Tags: google-chrome, кэширование

Каждое обновление Google Chrome приносит много плюсов, но и немало минусов для разработчика. Сегодня, не знаю было ли обновление, я заметил что хром кэширует всё подряд без разборки. Приведу пример:

Разрабатываю сайт, всё как обычно. Таблицы стилей, js и тд. Когда я делаю изменения в файле таблицы стилей, соответственно оно должно изменяться после перезагрузки страницы, так было до недавнего времени. Теперь я должен очистить кэш (CTRL+SHIFT+i => Network => Disable cache, но тут маленькая приметка*While DevTools is open* ). Вопрос, могу ли я вернуть всё как было когда-то? Чтобы я вносил изменения в файле стилей и они применялись обычной перезагрузкой страницы, а не постоянным открыванием этой панели разработчика?

Answer (score 0):

На вскидку могу предложить такие варианты:

1. Можно работать в режиме "Инкогнито".
2. Можно использовать стороннее расширение, например, [CacheKiller](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap?hl=ru).
3. Можно использовать другой браузер (дело личных предпочтений, не холивара для).
4. Можно прописать в ярлыке для запуска Chrome параметры: `--disk-cache-size=0 --media-cache-size=0`.

Comment: блин, у меня такое чувство, что разработчики хрома делают всё возможное чтобы усложнить жизнь разработчикам веба.

Comment: Они просто не парятся насчет таких вещей, решая за пользователя, как ему лучше (часто это оправданно, но далеко не всегда!). Но проблема с кэшем у Хрома известная. Более того, он любит кэшировать абсолютно все подряд и часто, от favions до видео, заполняя диск ненужным хламом. Потому вот и приходится искать обходные пути. Например, для экономии места на диске и банально для ускорения работы можно перенести папки с кэшами (обычного и медиа-кэш) на RAM-Disk. Тоже требует некоторых услилий, конечно. Но в сети есть инструкции: https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/59573/

Comment: Я уже написал к этим уважаемым разработчикам, если найду другие пути решения, дам знать