# Как в инструментах разработчика chrome отключить кэширование файла?

Tags: google-chrome, кэширование, инструменты-разработчика

Когда пишешь сайт очень не удобно если браузер кеширует какие ни будь файлы (чаше всего css).

Конечно это происходит не сразу, через несколько дней.

Как можно в инструментах разработчика chrome отключить кэширование файла?

PS: Было уже что-то похожее: [Google Chrome кэширование после обновления / панель разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/582980/), но этот вопрос уже устарел.

Comment: Отключать кэширование надо в настройках вашего веб-сервера

Comment: @andreymal а по подробнее?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching

Comment: А если у меня нет веб-сервера? Ну я просто пишу HTML и открываю их в браузере? Или так ничего не будет кэшироваться?

Comment: Вроде никогда не встречал, чтобы обычные файлы кэшировались

Comment: @andreymal а как мне например настроить AMPPS, или сервер hugo?

Comment: Если AMPPS подразумевает Apache, значит читайте документацию Apache. И про hugo соответственно читайте документацию hugo, я вот в ней вижу опцию `--noHTTPCache` для `hugo server` например

Comment: [How to disable your browser cache](https://www.webinstinct.com/faq/how-to-disable-browser-cache)

Comment: @Simon то же самое написано и по ссылке в тексте вопроса, но, видимо, автора не устраивает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Залучше разработчику всё таки отключать кеш в инструментах разработчика вкладка ***Network -> Disable cache*** - поставить галочку

Comment: Спасибо обоим..

Answer (score 1):

Во вкладке Network галочка Disable Cache. Потом нажми в "отдельном окне", сверни и работай без кеша

Comment: Что-то оба ответа про одно и тоже...

Comment: одновременно писали)